# obexftp is not working on all devices

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora, android, bluetooth

I use bluetooth to transfer files between by Fedora 26 (with KDE) box and my Android devices. I have 4 devices paired, 2 mobile phones and 2 tables. The Android versions are 5 & 7.
My problem: File Transfer (obexftp) is enabled in only ONE device (an HTC M7 phone with Android 5) and I don't know how to enable it for the other 3! The main reason is that I have no idea how the "File Transfer" was enabled in the first place.

On the other 3 devices I can SENT file from the Fedora Box to them and vice versa, but the obexftp is not working. When I try to open an obexftp connection to them via Dolphin, Dolphin simply refuses to do so.

From the CLI (bluetoothctl):

The output of the HTC (The device in which the File transfer works):

```
Alias: HTC M7
Class: 0x5a020c
Icon: phone
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: no
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PANU                      (00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: NAP                       (00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: SIM Access                (0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Vendor specific           (00006675-7475-7265-6469-616c62756d70)
Modalias: bluetooth:v000Fp1200d1436
```

On the other hand, the devices that don't have the obexftp enabled, look like this:

```
Name: Redmi
Alias: Redmi
Class: 0x5a020c
Icon: phone
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: yes
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PANU                      (00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: NAP                       (00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: SIM Access                (0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Modalias: bluetooth:v000Fp1200d1436
```

From the Android side, all devices have exactly the same bluetooth settings, so, I am suspecting that either the bluetooth implementation on the 3 devices is not the same as the HTC's or I need to do something on my Fedora. 
Any help to identify what I need to change/enable would be highly appreciated.